# Selenium moving to absolute positions

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm using the python package to move the mouse in some specified pattern or just random motions.

The first thing I tried is to get the size of the `//html` element and use that to make the boundaries for mouse movement. However, when I do this the `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException` rears its head and displays some "given" coordinates (which were not anywhere near the input.

The code I used:

`origin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html')
bounds = origin.size
print bounds
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(origin).move_by_offset(bounds['width'] - 10, bounds['height'] - 10).perform()`

So I subtract 10 from each boundary to test it and move to that position (apparently the `move_to_element_by_offset` method is dodgy).

`MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: Given coordinates (1919, 2766) are outside the document. Error: MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError: The target scroll location (17, 1798) is not on the page.
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.mouseMoveTo (file://...`

The actual given coordinates were (`1903-10=1893, 969-10=989`).

Any ideas?

Comment: try to use body instead of html in origin

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't help. (same result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was that I was not waiting for the element to load. At least I assume that's what the problem is because if I allow selenium to wait for the element instead and then click on it, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible problems:

1) There could be scroll on the page, so before clicking you should have scroll into element view

2) Size is given without browser elements respect, and in real world you should substitute about 20 or 30 to have original size (you could test test that values)

Comment: OK. Two questions: 

Doesn't the page scroll to the element when using move_to_element?

And why 20 or 30 despite the returned coords being off by a few hundred?

Comment: Within firefox with native events turned on - will scroll depending on circumstances, there are a lot of bugs with that issue on the selenium bugtracker.  For the second question - depending on the screen resolution and installed plugins, interface and so on the size will be different. For example if you will run the same on phantomjs (headless webkit browser), the coordinates will be correct for the same commands, that's because there is no any additional interface for it.

Comment: But how do I get the document size, so I know where not to move to?